# problema constrains xcode

Tags: xcode, iphone

Buenas tardes. Tengo terminada mi app con unos cuantos botones, el problema viene cuando lo cambio de pantalla y paso a iphone 6 por ejemplo o cualquier otra pantalla.

He probado multitud de combinaciones, se os ocurren ejemplos de constrains para que se adapte? aunque solo sea dentro de los iphones, no me importaria hacer la misma para ipad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Olvidar el recuadro blanco que aparece en la esquina inferior derecha.

Comment: Pues yo empezaría con el botón de abajo a la izda, el del mando. Le fijaría distancia fija hacia el bottom y distancia fija hacia Leading. Fijaria tb el de la derecha con el bottom y el trailing y luego la distancia entre ellos que la distancia sea mayor o igual. Cuando cambies a iPhone 6plus esa distancia se alargara. Los botones de arriba diría que están alineados por el bottom y que tiene el trailing y el lea din con los botones de abajo. van por ahi los tiros?

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con Add Missing Constraints?
En el botón de Resolve Auto Layout Issues.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Borra los Constraints anteriores en la opción "Clear Constraints" y luego "Add Missing Constraints". Eso debería ayudar un poco.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías eliminar todas las restricciones y posicionamiento estático de los elementos que componen la pantalla y crear `constraints` dinámicas que te permitan posicionar los elementos en función del tamaño de la pantalla.

Por ejemplo, comenzaría con el botón superior situándolo en el centro de la pantalla. Para ello debes ir al Size Inspector y con el botón derecho seleccionar el elemento a posicionar:

-ICONO CENTRAL SUPERIOR:

- "Center Horizontally in View" con View.
- "Top Space to View" con View.

ICONOS INFERIORES 1ª FILA:

*Izquierdo:

- "Top" con Icono Central Superior. (espacio vertical respecto el icono superior)
- "Leading Space to View" con View. (espacio lateral respecto a la vista)

*Derecho:

- "Top" con Icono Central Superior. (espacio vertical respecto el icono superior)
- "Leading Space to View" con Icono Izquierdo 1ª Fila. (espacio lateral respecto al icono de la misma fila)

ICONOS INFERIORES 2ª FILA:

*Izquierdo:

- "Top" con Icono Inferior 1ª Fila. (espacio vertical respecto el icono de la fila superior)
- "Leading Space to View" con View. (espacio lateral respecto a la vista)

*Derecho:

- "Top" con Icono Inferior 1ª Fila. (espacio vertical respecto el icono de la fila superior)
- "Leading Space to View" con Icono Izquierdo 2ª Fila. (espacio lateral respecto al icono de la misma fila)

De esta forma conseguirás posicionar los elementos independientemente del tamaño que tenga la pantalla.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.